# Android: How to get rid of @Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")?

Tags: android, json, annotations

I am using [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/tree/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin) to generate JSON files working with [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in my project.

I got a special module for that, and it produce almost what I need except the `@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")` annotation that I don't know how to get rid off.

So how do I get rid of that annotation or how to make it compile? Now it's not compiling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the next dependency

```
compile 'org.glassfish.main:javax.annotation:4.0-b33'
```

Answer (score 2):

add javax.annotation jar to your project path